# Javascript: Unicode symbol picker (for adding math symbols to a textarea)

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

I'm looking for a solution to allow users to add unicode characters (math symbols for now) to a textarea by clicking a button. I was hoping there was some kind of symbol picker class/plugin out there that would do this so I didn't have to recreate the wheel here.

I found [this one](http://macchiato.com/picker/MyApplication.html) but it's basically a proof of concept. Does anyone know of anything that's a bit more finished? A jQuery plugin would be great but I haven't found any yet.

### EDIT

I also found [this one](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/charpicker.html). It seems to be based on the same source though and also attempts to render unsupported characters.

Comment: The page you refer to contains a rather complete character picker, so if you want something more, I think you should clarify why it does not meet your (or your users’) needs.

Comment: If you look at that one, there are a ton of characters that it attempts to render that are not valid.  I will most likely try to customize that code.  Just looking for other options really.

Comment: It is a bit complex to know in JS which character is available in a font. This picker does what any other picker would normally do: let the underlying OS display the characters if it can, or a "I don't have this glyph" sign (square, whatever) if it can't.

Answer (score 1):

I've made 2 extensions, with the functionality you are looking for.

Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/utf-8-and-unicode-charact/fcemphgmjnjpmmdhcedhjiegickfbiia

Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/utf8-characters/

Here you can find only the math symbols in html:

https://github.com/codexico/UTF-8-Chrome-Extension/blob/master/html/groups/math.html

And the chars with description:

https://github.com/codexico/UTF-8-Chrome-Extension/blob/0361f41452f3c2165324dac437ff7ffa60b267f2/popup.html